# How does exactly "do-release-upgrade -d" work?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, lts, do-release-upgrade

About to upgrade the OS from one version to other, for example - from 18.04 to 20.04 or from 20.04 to 22.04 - throughout the process exists and is used the `do-release-upgrade` command, and it has some options such as `-c` and `-d`, now in the following tutorial

- [How To Upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 LTS using command line](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-lts-using-command-line/)

In the **Step 4. Upgrade Ubuntu Linux to latest LTS** section indicates the following:

> Execute the following command:
>
> `sudo do-release-upgrade`
>
> Please note if you may be greeted with the following message:
>
> ```
> Checking for a new Ubuntu release There is no development version of
> an LTS available. To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release 
> set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
> ```
>
> In that case, pass the `-d` option to get the latest supported release **forcefully**:
>
> `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

In the `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` file currently it has the `Prompt=lts` value - according with some research this value/setting is recommendable

Should I assume that if `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` is executed then

1. The current `Prompt=lts` value is ignored and is used `Prompt=normal` temporally ? - it only for the process execution life time
2. The current `Prompt=lts` value is is ignored and is used `Prompt=never` temporally ? - it only for the process execution life time
3. The current `Prompt=lts` value is is overridden to `Prompt=normal`? - therefore now is permanently changed
4. The current `Prompt=lts` value is is overridden to `Prompt=never` - therefore now is permanently changed

... and the process goes on

Currently the `man do-release-upgrade` for the `-d` option indicates

```
 -d, --devel-release
        If using the latest supported release, upgrade to the development release
```

But sadly is not clear.

**Question:**

- How does exactly `do-release-upgrade -d` work?

**Extra Questions**

- What scenario is applied? 1,2,3,4?
- When/why would be mandatory use `do-release-upgrade -d`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question pops up every two years, soon after each LTS release, in various forms.

`-d` does indeed migrate you to the *development* release of Ubuntu. That's currently 22.10 Kinetic, NOT 22.04 Jammy.

**BEFORE the release** of an LTS, using -d from the older release (like 21.10) will indeed upgrade you to the pre-release 22.04.  That's how testers get to the development release to do their testing.

- The use of `-d` means "I want to be a tester".

**ON RELEASE DAY**, there is no automatic mechanism to change the behavior of `-d`. So for a couple weeks afterward, `-d` will still migrate you to 22.04, even though it has been released.

- This is the window when those "use `-d`" articles appear. That advice has an expiration date, and it's irresponsible of the folks giving that advice when they fail to so explain.

**ABOUT A WEEK OR TWO after release day**, the Ubuntu Developers begin working on the next release (22.10 Kinetic), and they move `-d` from pointing at 22.04 to pointing at 22.10.

- This is the window when NEITHER `do-release-upgrade` nor `do-release-upgrade -d` will migrate you from 20.04 to 22.04. Instead, `-d` on 20.04 will return an error message, and the use of `-d` on 22.04 will make you a 22.10 tester.

**THREE MONTHS after release day**, the first LTS point release occurs (22.04.1). **This is when LTS-to-LTS release-upgrades are turned on**. This is when your 20.04.x system will begin to offer you a release-upgrade to 22.04.1.

Recall that the whole point of an LTS Release is long-term stability and reliability. Ubuntu developers and testers use that three-month delay to work out the early bugs and test the migration so it's smooth.

- Folks who want to migrate immediately are often not the intended audience for an LTS. If you are an early adopter, consider using a normal 6-month release of Ubuntu.
- LTS users should simply be patient. Wait for the tested, safe upgrade window to open in August.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed information about the schedule ... So now, I see is very important use the `-c` option

Comment: Currently seems I have your 3rd scenario - For the `20.04.4 LTS` through the `do-release-upgrade [-c]` command it indicates that there is nothing to upgrade - is suggested to edit `Prompt` to _normal_ - When I do that and is used then `do-release-upgrade -c` then is indicated that exists `21.10` - if is returned to `Prompt=lts` and is executed `do-release-upgrade -d` then appears the `authenticate 'jammy.tar.gz' against 'jammy.tar.gz.gpg'` line - because appears the `jammy` term, seems it is the correct approach - could you pls share some orientation?

Comment: So wondered why a lot of tutorials offer the instructions to do an upgrade just few days after the release of LTS, it from `20.04` - they never include  the important situations/scenarios you had indicated - their tutorials use the `-d` option and theoretically the upgrade process is accomplish successfully - it should not happen according with your latest bullet point

Comment: About _the first LTS point release occurs (22.04.1)_ sentence - so why in ubuntu.com right now offers `22.04 LTS` to be downloaded? I mean, why right now already appears the `LTS` term? - observe the difference between your `22.04.1` and current `22.04`

Answer (score 2):

The command `do-release-upgrade -d` will cause a development release to be installed, as stated in the man page. If you are on 20.04, and add the `-d` option, you will currently (2022-06-06) receive a message that `There is no development version of an LTS available.`. The tool will inform you that you can set `Prompt=normal` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` to upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release.

Of your scenario's, none will apply. Your configuration file will not be overridden. With `Prompt=lts`, and the option `-d`, you will only upgrade to a development release of the next LTS if it is available (*and* if your current version is an LTS - otherwise, that setting will be treated as set to `normal`), with `Prompt=normal`, and option `-d`, you will upgrade to the development release that immediately follows your current release.