# Has Ubuntu 24.04 already been released?

Tags: upgrade

I was running updates on two test servers (used to test new Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server releases) in anticipation of next month's release and accidentally ran the script to update to the next release. Typically, this is not a problem since it should come back with a message that no release was found.
Instead, it started going through the install process for 24.04. That's not supposed to be released until late next month.The script uses the usual do-release-upgrade -d command to run the distro upgrade. Both test servers were already at 23.10 and the package manager was showing tarballs with the name "noble".   Has it been released or is this some mistake and I'm installing a test release?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does exactly "do-release-upgrade -d" work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412543/how-does-exactly-do-release-upgrade-d-work). Classic misuse of `-d`

Comment: Ubuntu *noble* is still in *alpha* and hasn't yet even reached *beta* release. If you scan https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release you won't even find mention of the release; so *release-upgrade* tools will **NOT** find it; unless you specify `-d` causing the *development* version (https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development - note it's listed there) of that file to be found. As *noble* is approaching *beta* the *release-upgrade* will be getting closer to be QA tested thus infrastructure is being setup for QA purposes.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412543/how-does-exactly-do-release-upgrade-d-work) AskUbuntu post:

> BEFORE the release of an LTS, using -d from the older release (like 21.10) will indeed upgrade you to the pre-release 22.04. That's how testers get to the development release to do their testing.

> The use of -d means "I want to be a tester".

How I understand the command `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` (`-d` is short for development) is "Upgrade (do it forcefully if needed) even if unstable and/or pre-release"

`sudo do-release-upgrade` was the command that would upgrade only if the version was or is already released.

No, this is not a mistake, you *specifically* asked for the pre-release, even if you didn't know it. So just change your script to contain `sudo do-release-upgrade` instead of `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` if you don't want Ubuntu to update to the pre-release version.